# How do I log a stacktrace using java's Logger class

Tags: java, logging, stack-trace, java.util.logging

I am using Java's `Logger` class. I want to pass `ex.printStackTrace()` into `Logger.log(loglevel, String)`, but `printStackTrace()` returns `void`. So I am not able to pass and print the stack trace of the exception.

Is there any way that I can convert `void` into `String`, or are there any other methods to print the whole stack trace of exceptions?

Comment: in short : NO, u can not.

Comment: Sure, use this: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable) from commons-lang3 3.4

Comment: What sort of string value would "nothing" be turned into?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to understand that `void` is actually `nothingness`. You cannot convert what is nothing. You might end up printing `void` as a string, but (trust me), you don't want that.

I think what you are looking for is

```
// assuming ex is your Exception object
logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
// OR
Logger.log(errorLogLevel, ex.getMessage(), ex)
```

This will print the error message using the logger that you have configured. For more details, you can take a look at the java docs for [Exception#getMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage())

Comment: Thanks Saif Asif. I am able to log the whole stack trace now.

Comment: `logger.error()` is not `java.util.logging`, but I'm not going to downvote you because I am glad to discover `logger.log(Level, Exception, Supplier)` . Looks like Oracle have made `java.util.logging.Logger` seriously ugly! Since they were doing that, it's strange that they didn't take it further and create `logger.severe(String, Exception)` etc

Comment: The question asks for a solution using Java's Logger class. java.util.logging.Logger does not have a method called "error". I have downvoted this answer only because of that.

Comment: @Adam I agree that logger.error() looks ugly, but it is highly readable, and it is the way it is done in other simple languages like python, so it is not so terribly bad.

Comment: This is not answering the initial intention to print the stack trace to a logger, at all. getMessage() is not made for this.

Comment: So, the answer is:
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

Comment: The output is an exception, but no a stack of such

Answer (score 41):

Use [`java.util.logging.Logger#log(Level, String, Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-) and pass in `ex` as third argument like this:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage(), ex);
```

Comment: I'm not getting stack trace to log with this, only the second argument.

Comment: It is possible to suppress the stack trace by changing the log format. Which formatter are you using and how does your log format look like?

Comment: This is the real answer to the question.

Comment: @PanuHaaramo It depends on which formatter you use. The formatter needs to call `record.getThrown()` in `format`. Take a look at `SimpleFormatter`.

Answer (score 28):

Also another alternative would be:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

log.error("Exception : " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
```

Comment: If you're refering to org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils, it's
ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)

Answer (score 16):

There's an overloaded printStackTrace method that takes in a PrintWriter.

You can do something like this

```
Writer buffer = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(buffer);
ex.printStackTrace(pw);
Logger.log(loglevel, buffer.toString());
```

Comment: This is the simplest method IMHO and it really prints the stack trace, not only the message.

Answer (score 12):

With below format you can have the stack trace:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tF %1$tT [%4$-7s][%2$s] %5$s %6$s%n
```

The point in this pattern is %6$s. It will print the stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

You can't convert `void` into `String`; no such conversion exists.  `void` doesn't return *anything* back, so you have no value to retrieve.

What you probably want to do is get the message of the exception instead via [`ex.getMessage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage--).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) method to get an array of StackTraceElements, and generate a String from there. Otherwise, if just the final error message is sufficient, use the `getMessage()` method as suggested by Makoto.

To get the stack trace as a `String` from an array of `StackTraceElement` objects, you need to iterate over the array (taken from JDK7 source):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StackTraceElement[] trace = getOurStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement traceElement : trace)
        builder.append("\tat " + traceElement + "\n");
```

Another option is to use `printStackTrace(PrintStream s)`, where you get to specify where you want the stacktrace to be printed:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(out1);
ex.printStackTrace(out2);
String message = out1.toString("UTF8");
```

Comment: Just use the apache commons ExceptionUtils library; no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: 1. `String message = out1.toString("UTF8");` - compilation error, expected 0 parameterers, but got 1
2. It works correctly 
`out2.out.toString`.
In case `out2.toString` -> 'PrintStream@hash'

Comment: PrintStream uses UTF-8 by default or should encoding be specified by constructor ´PrintStream(String file, boolean autoFlush, Charset cs)´ ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **ExceptionUtils** if you need to see stacktrace without throwing Exception.

```
String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(new Exception("YourMessage"));
log.error(stackTrace);
```

Answer (score 1):

you CAN convert stacktrace into String using below. If `e` is the exception object

```
StringWriter stringWriter= new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter= new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
String stackTraceAsString= stringWriter.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I am able to log the stack trace details using

```
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage(),ex);
//ex is my exception object
```

Answer (score 0):

As Makoto says, you probably want to do an ex.getMessage().

To further clarify, `void` means that there is nothing returned. You can't cast nothing into something :)

Comment: He wants a stack trace, not just the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ExceptionUtils from apache library or below log statement

```
    try{
      doSomething();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Exception in method doSomething ",e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggestions all seem to just put the stack trace in the log without prefixing each line with the logger details. My suggestion below processes the stack trace elements and formats each line as a logger line:

```js
log.error("{}", e.toString());
StackTraceElement[] stElements = e.getStackTrace();

log.error("(stacktrace) {}", e.toString());

for (StackTraceElement ste: stElements) {
    log.error("(stacktrace)     at {}.{}({}.java:{})", 
        new Object[] {ste.getClassName(), ste.getMethodName(), 
                      ste.getClassName(), ste.getLineNumber()});
}

Throwable thisThrowable = e;
boolean causedBy = true;
while (causedBy) {
    Throwable throwable = thisThrowable.getCause();
    if (throwable != null) {
        log.error("(stacktrace) Caused by: {}", throwable.toString());
        stElements = throwable.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement ste: stElements) {
            log.error("(stacktrace)     at {}.{}({}.java:{})", 
                 new Object[] {ste.getClassName(), ste.getMethodName(),                    
                               ste.getClassName(), ste.getLineNumber()});
        }
        thisThrowable = throwable;  // For the next caused-by check
    } else {
        log.error("(stacktrace) No Caused-by Exception");
        causedBy = false;  // No more caused-by Throwables, so end the loop
    }
}
```

Each line of the stack trace is prefixed with "(stacktrace)". This has the advantage of being able to filter them out when dumping log files, or to be able to find them easily.

Answer (score 0):

With java.util.Arrays you can also solve this easily:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
}
```

Arrays.toString(Object[] a) calls Object.toString() for each element or returns a String with "null" if the object is null. The elements are separated by a comma and a space. StackTraceElement implements toString(), so the array you get from e.getStackTrace() converts nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Below set of code can be used.

```
public static Connection openConnection()  {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            // load the driver
            
            //System.out.println("Load JDBC Driver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("FAILED TO LOAD JDBC DRIVER");
            //System.out.println("Fail to Load JDBC Driver ");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log.error("Add some message, otherwise we wont get stacktrace with out some message ", exception)
```

This will display stacktrace.